# cordova-plugin-contacts plugin of cordova not produces correct result for searching phoneNumbers in ios

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, contacts, phone-number

cordova-plugin-contacts(plugin) of cordova not produces correct result for searching phoneNumbers in ios.
There are many contacts preloaded in contacts app.
I am using cordova 5.4.0 and plugin is [cordova-plugin-contacts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-contacts) and build application for iOS platform.

Below is code for searching PhoneNumbers into contacts.

```
    function findContacts(){
        var options      = new ContactFindOptions();
        options.filter   = "1234567890";
        options.multiple = true;
        options.desiredFields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.displayName, navigator.contacts.fieldType.name];
        options.hasPhoneNumber = true;

        var fields = [navigator.contacts.fieldType.phoneNumbers];

        navigator.contacts.find(fields, onFindSuccess, onFindError, options);
    }

    function onFindSuccess(contacts) {                
        alert("Contact: " + JSON.stringify(contacts));
    };

    function onFindError(contactError) {
        alert("onError!");
    };
```

It returns empty array even contact with phone number 1234567890 available in contacts list.

After some research for other search fields, while checking whole JSON string, I found that Phone numbers saved in contacts list has specific format.

for Example:

home: 1 (234) 567-890

work: 0987654321

mobile: (678) 901-2345

Now, I got result for work phone number 0987654321. But when try for home phone number 1 (234) 567-890 with same format, it gives an empty array. Am I missing something?

Is there any solution that works for all type of Phone Number formats?